# How to perform a loop inside a temporary DataTable and update a SQL Table after comparing values between both tables

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am developing a simple `asp.net web form` and I already have a SQL table.

The `WebForm` has a `repeater` control populated with data bound from a temporary `DataTable`. This temporary `DataTable` is populated from a real table inside my SQL database.

The user can edit each item from this repeater and/or exclude or insert new items, only modifying this temporary `DataTable`.

I already created the temporary DataTable and I am able to perform CRUD operations (`Create`, `Read`, `Update` and `Delete`) but, I need to place a save button on the bottom of the page, which performs a save operation and save all the revised data to the real table inside my SQL database...

I'm thinking about how to create the procedure to make a loop inside this temporary `DataTable` and compare to the real Table inside the SQL database.

Since I can edit, delete and create new items inside the `repeater` and inside the temporary `DataTable`, I do not know how to use a kind of primary key to compare the values and check if the real table has the item and needs to update or delete or insert a new item...

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder how you managed to store all changes that the user made in this DataTable. You store it in the Session? Thats not a good idea. Why don't you update the database directly whenever the user makes changes?

Comment: I use the viewstate to store the datatable. During each procedure, I call back the datatable from the viewstate... It is working... Regarding updating the database directly, our initial plan was create a webform that allow the user to change the table, allowing the user to cancel this edition. So, that's why I came with the temporary datatable.

Comment: sure it's working. But yiu blow the client HTML with your table even if all Informations are already available in the repeater. Apart from that it's not a good approach because caching changes means your data might be outdated because other user changed them meanwhile

Comment: Each row has a AcceptChanges and a RowState that can help you with the state of the update.

Comment: DataTables are very smart; they keep track of changes. Maybe create a DataAdapter; give it the appropriate Insert, Update and Delete commands. Then DataAdapter.Update(your temp DataTable)

Comment: Thanks @the_lotus. I think the trick is to use rowstate. However, when I call rowstate for each row inside my temporary datatable, after I press the save all button, the rowstate keeps returning only Unchanged value, even I insert a new item, modify or delete an existing item.